# "Value of ContainerControlledLifetimeManager can only be set once" when using an open-generic singleton registration

Tags: unity-container

I'm using the `Unity.Container` NuGet package 5.11 and I want to register an open-generic type such that each concrete type is a singleton.

Background: I'm working in an old-school ASP.NET WebForms application and I've made a crude reimplementation of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` like so:

```
// `ILogger` is implemented elsewhere. Specifically I wrote an implementation using Serilog.
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log( LogLevel level, String messageTemplate, params Object[] args ); 
}

// Unlike `ILogger`, this `ILogger<TSourceContext>` is not implemented by the code elsewhere (that uses Serilog, described above).
// Instead, it's only implemented by the internal class below:
public interface ILogger<TSourceContext> : ILogger
{
}

internal class LoggerWithSourceContext<TSourceContext> : ILogger<TSourceContext>
{
    private readonly ILogger realLogger;

    internal LoggerWithSourceContext( ILoggerFactory factory )
    {
        if( factory == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));
        this.realLogger = factory.CreateLogger( sourceContext: typeof(TSourceContext).FullName );
    }

    public void Log( LogLevel level, String messageTemplate, params Object[] args )
    {
        this.realLogger.Log( level, messageTemplate, args );
    }
}

// This is implemented elsewhere in my Serilog code.
public interface ILoggerFactory
{
    ILogger CreateLogger( String sourceContext );
}
```

This is registered in my root Unity container like so:

```
IUnityContainer rootContainer = ...
rootContainer
    .RegisterSingleton<ILoggerFactory,MySerilogLoggerFactory>()
    .RegisterSingleton( from: typeof(ILogger<>), to: typeof(LoggerWithSourceContext<>);
```

When this is used, the first time an `ILogger<T>` is resolved it works fine - however the *second* time an `ILogger<T>` is resolved it fails with this error:

> `InvalidOperationException`
>   ContainerControlledLifetimeManager can only be set once

I was able to work-around it by changing the registration from a Singleton to a Transient registration using `RegisterType`, but I'd like it to use a Singleton registration to mitigate the risks of a memory or resource leak:

```
IUnityContainer rootContainer = ...
rootContainer
    .RegisterSingleton<ILoggerFactory,MySerilogLoggerFactory>()
    .RegisterType( from: typeof(ILogger<>), to: typeof(LoggerWithSourceContext<>);
```

Full stack trace:

```
ContainerControlledLifetimeManager can only be set once
-2146233079
System.InvalidOperationException
   at Unity.Lifetime.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager.<>c.<SetValue>b__7_0(Object o, ILifetimeContainer c) in C:\projects\unity\Abstractions\src\Lifetime\Managers\ContainerControlledLifetimeManager.cs:line 70
   at Unity.Lifetime.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager.SetValue(Object newValue, ILifetimeContainer container) in C:\projects\unity\Abstractions\src\Lifetime\Managers\ContainerControlledLifetimeManager.cs:line 70
   at Unity.Strategies.LifetimeStrategy.PostBuildUp(BuilderContext& context) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Strategies\LifetimeStrategy.cs:line 86
   at Unity.UnityContainer.<>c.<.ctor>b__41_3(BuilderStrategy[] chain, BuilderContext& context) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\UnityContainer.Resolution.cs:line 431
   at Unity.Builder.BuilderContext.Resolve(Type type, String name, InternalRegistration registration) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Builder\Context\BuilderContext.cs:line 177
   at Unity.Builder.BuilderContext.Resolve(Type type, String name) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Builder\Context\BuilderContext.cs:line 67
   at Unity.Builder.BuilderContext.Resolve(ParameterInfo parameter, Object value) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Builder\Context\BuilderContext.cs:line 217
   at Unity.Processors.ConstructorProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<GetResolverDelegate>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Constructor\ConstructorResolution.cs:line 77
   at Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Abstracts\MemberProcessor.cs:line 162
   at Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Abstracts\MemberProcessor.cs:line 162
   at Unity.Processors.MemberProcessor`2.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetResolver>b__0(BuilderContext& c) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Processors\Abstracts\MemberProcessor.cs:line 162
   at Unity.Strategies.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(BuilderContext& context) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\Strategies\BuildPlanStrategy.cs:line 88
   at Unity.UnityContainer.<>c.<.ctor>b__41_2(BuilderContext& context) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\UnityContainer.Resolution.cs:line 363
   at Unity.UnityContainer.Unity.IUnityContainer.Resolve(Type type, String name, ResolverOverride[] overrides) in C:\projects\unity\Container\src\UnityContainer.IUnityContainer.cs:line 244
```

Answer (score 0):

Now in latest unity version 5.11.7 this problem fixed